# set default value using condition angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here I am creating dropdown and setting default value.And this is my object

```
$scope.currentprop={
            name : "graphFillDirection",
            members : [{
                name : "ttb",
                caption : "Top to Bottom",
            }, {
                name : "btt",
                caption : "Bottom to Top"
            }, {
                name : "ltr",
                caption : "Left to Right"
            },{
                name : "rtl",
                caption : "Right to Left"
            }
            ],
            value : "ttb",
            //suppose  it is : value:""
        }
```

In this object i have `members` array and property `value`. So checking with iteraing `members.name` and `value` property and this is my html.

```
<select ng-model="currentprop.value" ng-options="value.name as value.name  for (key,value) in currentprop.members" ng-selected="{{currentprop.value == value.name}}"></select>
```

if the case `currentprop.value == value.name` matches then i set the value to ng-model. My question is if currentprop.value to be like `value:""` then the iterated value never get matched with `currentprop.value`. so what i need is if `value:""` then i set the `members[0].name` to the ng-model. some please help me. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/71qJrIdn82vWbG6MOadR?p=preview&s=L9ccLxuTWPU3lheh) here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ng-init` in the `select`:

```
<select ng-model="currentprop.value" 
   ng-init="currentprop.value = currentprop.value || currentprop.members[0].name"
   ng-options="value.name as value.name  for (key,value) in currentprop.members" 
   ng-selected="{{currentprop.value == value.name}}">
 </select>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RAVf4cxNorjsLbiFWP8H?s=L9ccLxuTWPU3lheh&p=preview)

Comment: `ng-init` is nice, but slow.. don't use this very often. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it's a big improvement – reduce count of filters and bunch if directives like (ng-init, ng-mouseover, ng-mouseleave, ng-include), it's super unefficient

Comment: Developers have been using `window/document.onload` eventhandlers in JQuery/javascript for a while. `ng-init` works the same. Not inefficent.

Comment: Out of context, did you even read it?  `currentprop.value` has its own `scope`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set currentprop.value to members[0].name in Ctrl:

```
$scope.currentprop={
        name : "graphFillDirection",
        members : [{
            name : "ttb",
            caption : "Top to Bottom",
        }, {
            name : "btt",
            caption : "Bottom to Top"
        }, {
            name : "ltr",
            caption : "Left to Right"
        },{
            name : "rtl",
            caption : "Right to Left"
        }
        ],
        value : "",
    };
 $scope.currentprop.value = $scope.currentprop.value=="" ? $scope.currentprop.members[0].name : $scope.currentprop.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If currentprop.value can't be changed to `""` during the app life after loading then this solution will work perfect for you:

```
$scope.currentprop={
        name : "graphFillDirection",
        members : [{
            name : "ttb",
            caption : "Top to Bottom",
        }, {
            name : "btt",
            caption : "Bottom to Top"
        }, {
            name : "ltr",
            caption : "Left to Right"
        },{
            name : "rtl",
            caption : "Right to Left"
        }
        ],
        value : "",
    };

 $scope.currentprop.value = $scope.currentprop.value || $scope.currentprop.members[0].name;
```

If it can be changing after controller initialized you need to do something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('currentprop.value', function(value) {
  if (value !== '') {
    $scope.currentprop.value = $scope.currentprop.members[0].name;
  }
});
```

Note: if you add watcher then you don't have to add `$scope.currentprop.value = $scope.currentprop.value || $scope.currentprop.members[0].name;` from first example, vecause watcher fires automatically at init.

**Optimisation**

Also `ng-options` can be simplified `ng-options="value.name as value.name  for value in currentprop.members"`

You don't need to add `ng-selected` while you have `ng-model` in `<select>`. `ng-model` selects options automatically.

**Default placeholde**

If you need a default option to be a placeholder like "Select member", you can do this:

```
<select ng-model="currentprop.value"
        ng-options="value.name as value.name for value in currentprop.members">
  <option value="">Select a member</option
</select>
```